# Привязка операции "=" к клавише Enter.

Tags: java, калькулятор

Пишу простой GUI калькулятор с возможностью ввода значений с клавиатуры на java.  Определение требуемой операции реализовал таким образом:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()) {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            char symvol = e.getKeyChar();
            if(symvol=='+'){
                first_velue = Integer.valueOf(output.getText());
                output.setText("");
                operation ="+";

            }
      }
}
```

Нужно привязать нажатие кнопки `Enter` к операции "=". Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

 }
```